# simple question about substring in C#

Tags: c#, string, substring

This is perhaps too easy but I do not know from where to start.

I have stings like "'02HEX'aspoodsasas'CR''LF'"

Now I want to extract stings between char(02) and char(12);

Until now I did following

```
string s = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", (char)02, "12345678", (char)12);
int chindx = s.IndexOf((char)02)+1;
s = s.Substring(chindx, 8)
```

My problem is how to determine length of my substring if I know position of start character and position of my ending character in my string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just subtract:

```
string middle = text.Substring(start, end - start);
```

(That's assuming you *don't* want the character at position `end` - if you do, just add one.)

For example:

```
string text = "hi there";
int start = 3; // 't'
int end = 6; // 'r'
string middle = text.Substring(start, end - start); // "the"
```

Comment: Thanks, I really need more sleep, When I see where I get stacked.

Comment: Thank you.But SubString(startPoint ,endPoint) often comes out instinctly.

Answer (score 1):

A simple subtraction should do the trick. End position - Start position (minus the length of the first token)